migrate oracle GRID 12c to 19c
i'm not an expert oracle , i would like to migrate oracle GRID 12c to 19c  using rman
in order to test the possibility
do you have any guide or deocument to perform this operation;
thank you for your support and suggestions .

When in doubt, check the Oracle documentation: https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/twp-upgrade-oracle-database-19c.pdf
Are you planning to use RMAN to clone your 12c database so that you can then perform an in-place upgrade as a test? Are you planning to perform an in-place upgrade and then use RMAN to rollback to the original version? Are you planning to use RMAN to transfer a pluggable database from a 12c container database to a 19c container database?
Whether RMAN is a suitable part of your upgrade strategy will depend on several specifics including whether you are upgrading "in place" or installing a new Oracle Home for 19c, whether you are using multi-tenant architecture, whether you need to make changes to your storage architecture, what you need to migrate into Oracle 19c (e.g., just data, or other things like users, policies, and other system-level artifacts).
